# Runnable Jsoup.connect

Tags: java, android

When I start this Rannable with toast - it works! 
But when I try to get document throught Jsoup.connect it crushing app and show errors:

```
04-13 14:45:09.695: E/AndroidRuntime(1634): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-13 14:45:09.695: E/AndroidRuntime(1634): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
04-13 14:45:09.695: E/AndroidRuntime(1634):     at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1084)
04-13 14:45:09.695: E/AndroidRuntime(1634):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.recvfrom(IoBridge.java:503)
04-13 14:45:09.695: E/AndroidRuntime(1634):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.isStale(HttpConnection.java:256)
04-13 14:45:09.695: E/AndroidRuntime(1634):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnectionPool.get(HttpConnectionPool.java:71)
```

```
Runnable prs = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        Document doc = null;
        try {
            doc = Jsoup.connect("http://play.radio.com/").get();

        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        parser.postDelayed(prs, 10000);
    }
};
```

Also I cannot use AsyncTask because
I should start this code every 10 seconds and parsing page. I cannot run AsyncTask twice!

What to do?

Comment: run the code in an `AsyncTask`

Comment: I should start this code every 10 seconds and parsing page. I cannot run AsynkTask twice!